# How to display data as a pop up or as second layer?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook-like

I am developing a website and there is an option to upload images, provided with the features to crop it and upload it. Till now it was a separate page but now i want to display it as a link to first page and on clicking the link it should open a new frame (kinda like how facebook opens the images now) and display the options to select the image to upload along with cropping feature.

and i was posting an image here but due to points issue i am not allowed to so if you need to get the image idea just check a photo on your facebook account.

Comment: you need a "lightbox" like [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/)

Comment: @rcro are you certain that lightbox is the only option? i know that javascript seems the best way to do it but is there any other option like when we prepare for scenarios when javascript is not working due to any reason. will it be all ok if js is not enabled? i guess nothing will be displayed then?

Answer (score 0):

Look at at [JQuery Boxy](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/boxy/). It makes sense and looks much closer to facebook dialog

Comment: i saw the link and it seems like a good option but just want to know that is it better than clearbox??

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't specified a javascript framework, I thought I would suggest a plain javascript way to dynamically add an iframe to the current document. This is only really applicable if the picture uploading page is on the same server as the site that will deliver the iframe. Otherwise you probably want to use something other than frames...

```
function showIframe() {
            /* Parent element */
            var widget = document.createElement("div");
            widget.style.position="fixed";
            widget.style.top="100px";
            widget.style.left="100px";
            widget.style.width="300px";
            widget.style.height="200px";

            /* picture uploading page frame */
            var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
            iframe.src = "http://localhost"; // use your picture upload URL here

            /* Add to document */
            widget.appendChild(iframe);
            document.body.appendChild(widget);
}
```

and in the HTML add an element with a callback that calls showIframe() like:

```
<a onclick="showIframe()">Picture Widget</a>
```

Comment: hi and thank you for your help but when i tried this it worked but the window appeared to be very small and it wont change with the dimensions parameter in the code. also there is no option to close the window or make it disappear. i guess i have to dive into it and write all that code myself.